# Ubuntu python Qt import fail

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt5, git-cola

I am not able to launch git-cola on Ubuntu 20.04. As a troubleshooting exercise, I did this:

```
darnstein@EXTP346360104:Downloads$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QOpenGLWidget, version Qt_5
```

What should I do to resolve the undefined symbol?
I have packages python3-qt5 python3-pyqt5 installed already.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtopengl` should help.

Comment: What is "python3-qt5"? It isn't an official ubuntu package. I suggest you remove that, as it may cause a version conflict.